# User Login Report in Sharepoint Online?

Tags: office-365

Is there any way to get user login reports in SP Online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the audit log reports provided with SharePoint 2013 to view the data in the audit logs for a site collection. You can sort, filter, and analyze this data to determine who has done what with sites, lists, libraries, content types, list items, and library files in the site collection. For example, you can determine who deleted which content. SP Online has limitations.
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/view-audit-log-reports-HA102772739.aspx