# How to track logged in user daily in SharePoint online site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-rest-api

I need to store User detail in custom list including time log in SharePoint Online. I need to generate daily report for logged in user in SharePoint online Site.
Is it possible Programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the audit log reports provided with SharePoint 2013 to view the data in the audit logs for a site collection. You can sort, filter, and analyze this data to determine who has done what with sites, lists, libraries, content types, list items, and library files in the site collection.

Check This: [User Login Report in Sharepoint Online?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83855/user-login-report-in-sharepoint-online)

MSDN LINK [Configure audit settings for a site collection](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-A9920C97-38C0-44F2-8BCB-4CF1E2AE22D2)

Comment: Is it possible Programmatically? I need to store it custom list.

Answer (score 1):

**Audit report** is the best approach , you can export the audit log to a library or list if you need .

Or if you are a global admin , you can go to Admin center--Report--Usage , select SharePoint --user , under **Details** you can view the detail of user's actions .
 [image]